# Sprites and long text

Tags: css, sprite

Many coders embrace sprites but they seem to forget that sprites require more-less fixed containers. You cannot use srite on h2 if you cannot control it's height. H2 looks good when you have 1 (2) rows of text, but hell breaks loose when you have 3 rows -- next image from the sprite becomes visible.

Whats the best solution to fix it? Icon inside it's container?

```
<h2>
    <span class="ico">Text that needs to be hidden</span>
    Lorem ipsum<br />dolor sit<br />amet
</h2>
```

Another solution is to place images on sprite file diagonally, but this solution doesn't allow 100% 0 positioning.

What's your solution?

Comment: I suppose the answer is don't use a sprite for elements that have a variable width or height. You don't have to have _every_ image in a sprite.

Answer (score 6):

*Note the positioning of the red section in the images below*

If neither the width nor the height is variable, place the image
   anywhere in the sprite.

[image: No repeated section; place image anywhere in sprite]

---

If the height is variable but the width is fixed, you can try placing the background along the left or right edge of the sprite.  This will allow you to repeat-y.

[image: Position repeated section on left of sprite]

[image: Position repeated section on right of sprite]

---

If the width is variable but the height is fixed, you can try placing the background along the top or bottom edge of the sprite.  This will allow you to repeat-x.

[image: Position repeated section on top of sprite]

[image: Position repeated section on bottom of sprite]

---

If both the width and height are variable, I don't believe you can use an image in the sprite effectively.  You should just use a standard background image.

[image: Regular background image; no sprite]